# Spring boot Between two date Method Not Working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Am using Spring boot and Spring data Jpa with JpaReposity

am getting issue SpringBoot Jpa Query Method

***JPA Repo Method***

```
    List<BatteryEntity> findByCurrenDateAfterAndCurrenDateBefore(Date start, Date end);
```

This Mathod is working fine but issue when i pass 2 parameter as any date its working but when i pass new Date() as 2 parameter its working fine

***And Service Layer Class method***

```
        System.out.println("Start Date_______________" + startDate);
        System.out.println("Start Date_______________" + endDate);

        System.out.println(new Date());
        String startDate = "28/11/19";
        String endDate = "07/12/19";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter5 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        Date date1 = formatter5.parse(startDate);
        Date date2 = formatter5.parse(endDate);

        if(date2.after(new Date())){
            System.out.println("Date1 is after Date2");
        }
        // before() will return true if and only if date1 is before date2
        if(date2.before(new Date())){
            System.out.println("Date1 is before Date2");
        }


    List<BatteryEntity> blist = batteryRepo.findByCurrenDateAfterAndCurrenDateBefore(date1, date2);
    System.out.println(blist.size());
```

And output am getting

```
Start Date_______________27/11/19
Start Date_______________07/12/19
Sat Nov 30 22:53:16 IST 2019
Date1 is before Date2
0
```

But when i pass 2end Date as `new Date()` its give me Proper Value

```
List<BatteryEntity> blist = batteryRepo.findByCurrenDateAfterAndCurrenDateBefore(date1, new Date());

        System.out.println(blist.size());
```

and output

```
Start Date_______________27/11/19
Start Date_______________07/12/19
Sat Nov 30 22:57:44 IST 2019
Date1 is before Date2
3807
```

Comment: you can replace, findByCurrenDateAfterAndCurrenDateBefore(Date start, Date end) by findByCurrenDateBetween(Date start, Date end)

Comment: I also Try Between  but same issue

Comment: yes i found its working can you let me know why not working when both are date format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter5 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

with

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter5 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
```

Please check the following code and its output to understand the reason:

```
String startDate = "28/11/19";
String endDate = "07/12/19";

SimpleDateFormat formatter5 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date1 = formatter5.parse(startDate);
Date date2 = formatter5.parse(endDate);
System.out.println(date1);
System.out.println(date2);

formatter5 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
date1 = formatter5.parse(startDate);
date2 = formatter5.parse(endDate);
System.out.println(date1);
System.out.println(date2);
System.out.println(new Date());
```

**Output:**

```
Tue Nov 28 00:00:00 GMT 19
Thu Dec 07 00:00:00 GMT 19
Thu Nov 28 00:00:00 GMT 2019
Sat Dec 07 00:00:00 GMT 2019
Sat Nov 30 18:00:48 GMT 2019
```